# How did you learn Bayesian statistics and what would you recommend as a reliable source?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm running a Bayesian model and I'm stuck on some aspect of the model that I have difficulty to understand. Since my knowledge about Bayesian inference is limited, I would like to have some good references to understand Bayesian statistics.

People are teaching Bayesian statistics could be interested in how to think in [bayesian versus frequentist statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46912/how-would-you-approach-giving-an-introductory-class-about-bayesian-statistics). But I'm interested in finding [examples of model building](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/08/20/using-jags-in-r-with-the-rjags-package/) and how should we create, from scratch new models and diagnose them.

A good reference [is this book](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/), but I need something more practical.

Answer (score 2):

The book you linked (Gelman et al.) is eminently practical: the authors spend quite a few pages discussing real data and the gory details of choosing, fitting, and evaluating models. That's where I learned Bayesian stuff myself. If what you're looking for is something less mathematically intimidating, try John K. Kruschke's *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis*.